# Spark JDBC to Read and Write from and to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to come up with a generic implementation to use Spark JDBC to support Read/Write data from/to various JDBC compliant databases like PostgreSQL, MySQL, Hive, etc.

My code looks something like below.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Hive JDBC").setMaster("local[*]")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive JDBC Example")
  .getOrCreate()

val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://host1:10000/default")
  .option("dbtable", "student1")
  .option("user", "hive")
  .option("password", "hive")
  .option("driver", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
  .load()

jdbcDF.printSchema

jdbcDF.write
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default")
    .option("dbtable", "student2")
    .option("user", "hive")
    .option("password", "hive")
    .option("driver", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
```

**Output:**

```
root
    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- dept: string (nullable = true)
```

The above code works seamlessly for PostgreSQL, MySQL databases, but it starts causing problems as soon as I use Hive related JDBC config.

First, my read was not able to read any data and returning empty results. After some search, I could able to make read work by adding the custom HiveDialect but still, I'm facing issue in writing data to Hive.

```
case object HiveDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:hive2")
  override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = s"`$colName`"
  override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match {
    case StringType => Option(JdbcType("STRING", Types.VARCHAR))
    case _ => None
  }
}

JdbcDialects.registerDialect(HiveDialect)
```

**Error in Write:**

```
19/11/13 10:30:14 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.addBatch(HivePreparedStatement.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:834)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
```

How I can execute Hive Queries(Read/Write) from Spark to **Multiple Remote Hive Servers** using Spark JDBC?

I can't use Hive metastore URI approach since, in that case, I will be restricting myself with single Hive server config. Also as I mentioned earlier I want the approach to be generic for all the database types (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Hive) so taking the Hive metastore URI approach won't work in my case.

**Dependency Details:**

- Scala version: 2.11
- Spark version: 2.4.3
- Hive version: 2.1.1.
- Hive JDBC Driver Used: 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of context, and I am not sure whether it is relevant. However, the error is straightforward enough:

> Spark is not able to create the table in Hive with DataType "Text".

There is indeed no data type called Text in Hive, perhaps you are looking for one of the following:

- STRING
- VARCHAR
- CHAR

I hope this helps, otherwise please consider reducing your question to the bare minimum (while maintaining a reproducible example) to avoid distractions.

Comment: The problem here is, Spark is creating the table dynamically based on the schema of the DF. Is there a generic way to substitute the create table datatypes with the datatypes which are supported by Hive?

Comment: That sounds more like a challenge of working with multiple databases rather than something related to spark. I am not aware of a solution automatically transform data types from any database to another, but also can't say it does not exist! -- Given the limited number of data types it should not be that hard to apply a translation table that covers most cases in a reasonable way.

Comment: Yes, looks like extending the existing HiveDialect will do the trick. This link talks about the implementation of the same https://link.medium.com/jZsQwXsMy1 I will give it a try and post the final solution.

Comment: Updated the question. Now getting "java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported" error. Kindly suggest if you know any solution for the same.

Comment: Where did you get with this, would really appreciate knowing what solution you came up with

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin

Comment: Upon rereading I don't have much to add in regards to the original question. In case followup questions are needed please post a new question so it doesn't remain invisible (hidden inside this question)